# Is there a pdf or text file for manpages of all commands/utilities?

Tags: man

Is there a single pdf or text file for manpages of all commands/utilities?

I would like to add my comment to manpages which can be stored in my personal directory.

Depending on availability, this may be about

- man pages stored in some non-standard location
- how to edit man pages in general
- a way to concatenate all manpages in my system (Ubuntu 14.04) into a single file.

Comment: What do you mean _all_ utilities? All those installed in your system? All those in your distribution's repositories? All in the known universe? How does having all man pages in a single pdf help you edit them? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I would like to add my comment to manpages which are stored in my personal directory

Comment: You've been a member for 4 years. Surely by now you know that questions need to be precise and explanatory. Please [edit] and explain exactly what you're trying to do. If you're talking about man pages stored in some non-standard location, _say so_.  If you are asking how to edit man pages in general, again _say so_. If you just want a way to concatenate all manpages in your system into a single file, you need to make that clear. Explain what you need, give an example etc.

Comment: Right now, the answer to the only question actually asked is, "No". But that doesn't feel like it's answering what you think you want to ask. (And besides, it's too short for an SE answer.)

Comment: *Maybe*, but there isn't necessarily a file for all  `man` pages. [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/man.html): *The historical `$MANPATH` variable is not included in POSIX because no attempt is made to specify naming conventions for reference page files, nor even to mandate that they are files at all... [which may] be a database, a hypertext file, or even fixed ... within the man executable. [P]ortability of reference pages is outside [POSIX] scope... users should be aware that `$MANPATH` [may] ... be used to tailor the search pattern for reference pages...*

Comment: It seems to imply the possibility of an existing implementation which does a single `man.all` or something. It also *(conversely)* seems to imply that if you should know about it you probably already do. `ksh` and its related *ast* utilities actually compile in their `man` pages *(apart from offering the sources as well)* so that the `man` page can be found within the utility itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate all installed man pages into a single file, you could do:

```
cat /usr/share/man/man?/*gz > all.gz
```

You should also include any/all dirs that can be found in the environment variable `$MANPATH` or which can be found in the output of the command `manpath`.

You can then read the concatenated manpages as a single file by running

```
man -l all.gz
```

This is just a compressed text file so you can decompress it and edit to your heart's content.

You can also generate PDFs from it:

```
zcat all.gz | groff -mandoc | epstopdf -f -o all.pdf
```

Comment: @mikeserv don't know that at all. Should I include something like `cat /usr/share/man/man?/*gz "$MANPATH"/*gz`? If so, feel free to edit, I;ve never used that.

Comment: Thanks. If I download https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/man-pages-3.82.tar.gz, how can I concatenate them into a single file and a pdf file?